# Unable to create a Sandbox/Test account for my PayPal with a personal account

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

I've tried creating a Sandbox account in PayPal and couldn't create one without having to open a business account.

However, **I own no company** and I have a personal account.  And I want to be able to create a Sandbox account and be able to make test payments via my website to see how it works. Isn't it possible anymore to create a Sandbox/test account if you have only a personal account?

My goal is to make a test payment, by myself, as a customer on my website by going through all the steps.